# Sharepoint 2010 Listing of what pages a webpart is used on

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've been trying to use the object model and crawl a page and list all of the webparts that are on the page. I've been using powershell, but I'm open to other ideas.

the issue I'm having is when using the `GetLimitedWebPartManager` I get a listing of the webparts on a page, great so far. but if I change the title of the webpart I've been unable to link it back to the original webpart.

for example if I have a webpart  with the Title "my webpart" in the webpart Gallery, and I use it on page A. I see the webpart "my Webpart" in the powershell listing. If I add this webpart again on the page or another page and change the Title to " Your Webpart" it shows up on the list with the new Title, I have been unable to link the 2 webparts together, showing infact that this webpart is being used 2 times.

I've checked the `ID`, `Title`, `UniqueID`, `DisplayTitle` and can't see any link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to get the list of WebParts on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to link webparts by its type:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$f = $w.GetFile("default.aspx")
$m = $f.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$m.WebParts | % { $_.GetType().Name }
```

This code will output type for each webpart on a page, so you are able to recognize multiple usage of one webpart on the page (regardless of titles).